# Article: Invariant Sylow subgroups and solvability of finite groups - Antonio Beltran.

Tags: sylow-theory, invariant-theory, coprime

This is a article which Antonio Beltran. I'm reading lemma 2.2.b). I see that:

"Lemma 2.2. Suppose that A is a finite group acting coprimely on a finite group G, and let $C = C_G(A)$. Then, for every prime p,

(b) $ν_p(C)$ divides $ν_p^A (G)$ and $ν_p^A (G)$ divides $ν_p(G)$.

Proof:

(b) If P is an A-invariant Sylow subgroup of G, then by coprime action properties $P ∩C$ is a Sylow p-subgroup of C and obviously, $N_C (P) ⊆ N_C (P ∩C)$. Hence $ν_p(C) = |C : N_C (P ∩ C)|$ divides $ν_p^A (G) = |C : N_C (P)|$. On the other hand, by applying Lemma 2.1 to the A-invariant subgroup $N_G(P)$, we get that $ν_p^A (G) = |C : N_C (P)|$ divides $ν_p(G) = |G : N_G(P)|$."

I don't understand why "if $N_C (P) ⊆ N_C (P ∩C)$, then $ν_p(C) = |C : N_C (P ∩ C)|$ divides $ν_p^A (G) = |C : N_C (P)|$."

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/291552840_Invariant_Sylow_subgroups_and_solvability_of_finite_groups

Thank you very much.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3596916/a-invariant-sylow-p-subgroup  and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3527692/invariant-sylow-subgroups-and-solvability-of-finite-groups/3597648#3597648

Comment: I have solved all your questions with respect to the paper *Invariant Sylow subgroups and solvability of finite groups* of Antonio Beltrán. If you deem these to be the right ones, please tick them as such, as is the habit here on StackExchange. Thanks!