# If $K \triangleleft G$ and $P$ a Sylow p subgroup of a finite group $G$, then $K \cap N_G(PK)=\left\{e\right\}?$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I read something, see

Marshall Hall Jr., On the number of Sylow subgroups in a finite group, Journal of Algebra
Volume 7, Issue 3, December 1967, Pages 363–371 [DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(67)90076-2), Theorem 2.1

"The inverse image of $N_H(P^*)$ is $N_G(PK)$"

that suggested the following: If $K \triangleleft G$ and $P$ a Sylow p subgroup of a finite group $G$, then $K \cap N_G(PK)=\left \{ e \right\}$, where $N_G$ stands for the normalizer in $G$. Is this true? If so, does $P$ have to be a Sylow p subgroup of $G$?

Comment: Since $K\leq PK\leq N_G(PK)$, that intersection is trivial only if $K$ is trivial. And that holds for *any* subgroups $K$ and $P$ such that $KP$ is a subgroup.

Comment: What about the case $K=P=G$?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps these observations help. All groups mentioned are finite.

**Proposition 1** Let $H \leq G$ and $N \unlhd G$, with $N \subseteq H$. Then 
$$N_G(H)N/N=N_{G/N}(H/N)$$

**Proof** This relies heavily on the so-called *correspondence theorem*, moving back and forth between subgroups of a group and its quotients w.r.t. a fixed normal subgroup (see for example I.M. Isaacs, [Finite Group Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821843443), X.21 Theorem).

Since $H \unlhd N_G(H)$, we have $H/N \unlhd N_G(H)N/N$ and hence $N_G(H)N/N \subseteq N_{G/N}(H/N)$. For the converse containment put $N_{G/N}(H/N)=U/N$, with $U$ a (unique) subgroup of $G$ containing $N$. Now $H/N \unlhd N_{G/N}(H/N)$, so $H \unlhd U$, whence $U \subseteq N_G(H)$, so $U/N \subseteq N_G(H)N/N$ and we are done.

**Corollary 1** Let $H \leq G$ and $N \unlhd G$, then
$$N_G(HN)N/N=N_{G/N}(HN/N).$$ 
**Proof** In Proposition 1 instead of $H$, put this subgroup to be $HN$.

Observe that always $N_G(H)N \subseteq N_G(HN)$. Now, one probably tends to think that $N_G(HN)=N_G(H)N$, but in general this is not true.

However, if $H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup, then we have equality.

**Proposition 2** Let $P \in Syl_p(G)$, $N\unlhd G$, then
$$N_G(PN)=N_G(P)N.$$
Together with Corollary 1, this yields the following.

**Corollary 2** Let $P \in Syl_p(G)$, $N\unlhd G$, then
$$N_G(P)N/N=N_{G/N}(PN/N).$$
**Proof of Proposition 2** Note that $N_G(P) \subseteq N_G(PN)$ since $N$ is normal. Observe further that $P$ is Sylow in $N_G(PN)$, in fact we have $P \subseteq PN \unlhd N_G(PN)$, and we can apply the Frattini Argument: $$N_G(PN)=N_{N_G(PN)}(P)PN=(N_G(PN) \cap N_G(P))PN=N_G(P)PN=N_G(P)N,$$ concluding the proof.