# A-invariant Sylow p-subgroup

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, invariant-theory, frattini-subgroup

This is a article which Antonio Beltran. I'm reading lemma 2.2.c). I see that:

"Lemma 2.2. Suppose that A is a finite group acting coprimely on a finite group G, and let $C = C_G(A)$. Then, for every prime p,

(b) $ν_p(C)$ divides $ν_p^A (G)$ and $ν_p^A (G)$ divides $ν_p(G)$.

(c) if N is an A-invariant normal subgroup of G, then $ν_p^A (N)$ and $ν_p^A (G/N)$ divide $ν_p^A (G)$. "

In the proof c) below.  I don't understand why **$C=(C\cap N)N_C(P)$ deduces $C=(C\cap N)N_C(P\cap N)$**

[image]

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/291552840_Invariant_Sylow_subgroups_and_solvability_of_finite_groups[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Thank you very much.

Comment: As it say, it follows directly from $N_C(P) \subseteq N_C(P \cap N)$. What exactly do you not understand?

Answer (score 2):

Since $P \in Syl_p^A(G)$, and $N \unlhd G$ is $A$-invariant, we have $P \cap N$ is an $A$-invariant Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N$. The Frattini argument assures that $G=N_G(P \cap N)N$ and both $N_G(N \cap P)$ and $N$ are $A$-invariant. It follows (and this is 8.2.11 in Kurzweil-Stellmacher's *The Theory of Finite Groups, an introduction*, or Problem 3E.2 in Isaacs' *Finite Group Theory*) that $C=C_G(A)=C_{N_G(P \cap N)}C_N(A)=N_C(P \cap N)(N \cap C).$ Hope the proof is clear now, and I must admit Beltrán writes it all down somewhat confusingly.